# Passport returns "no username was given" when "usernameField" is set to "email"

Tags: express, authentication, mongoose, passport.js

I'm trying to use passport-local-mongoose for user authentication in an express app, but I want to use email instead of username so after some research I found that passport provides a way to do that by doing something like this:

```js
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password'
  },  
  function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function(err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect email.' });
      }
      if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
      }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));
passport.use(LocalStrategy);
User.authenticate();
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
```

But I'm still getting the "no username was given" error and it won't save the user to the database.

Comment: Are you sending the credentials in parameters called 'email' and 'password' in the body of your request?

Comment: Yes the inputs in the form have names of "email" and "password".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password'
  },  
  User.authenticate()
));
```